# Proper DNS suffix setup Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, systemd-networkd, resolv.conf

I have trouble getting DNS suffix to work properly

Basically, I have `jira.mycompany.local` in the company DNS server mapped to `192.168.100.5`

I want to be able to access it using both `jira` and `jira.mycompany.local`.

I have this in my `/etc/systemd/resolvd.conf`

```
[Resolve]
Domains=mycompany.local devnet.mycompany.nl
```

Restarting the Network manager & resolved:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

Results in this `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 192.168.10.1
nameserver 192.168.10.2
nameserver 127.0.0.53

search mycompany.local
search devnet.mycompany.nl
```

So this all looks good. Testing the DNS:

```
nslookup jira.mycompany.local
Server:     192.168.10.1
Address:    192.168.10.1#53

Name:   jira.mycompany.local
Address: 192.168.100.5
```

Ping to IP:

```
>ping 192.168.100.5
PING 192.168.100.5 (192.168.100.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=7.04 ms
```

Ping To hostname (with and without suffix):

```
>ping jira
ping: jira: Name or service not known

>ping jira.mycompany.local
ping: jira.mycompany.local: Name or service not known
```

Relevant line  of  `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

(I removed the avahi line so it won't interfere.)

Test using dig:

```
dig +short jira 
(empty)

dig +short jira.mycompany.local 
192.168.100.5
```

[EDIT]

I modified the hosts line in the etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
hosts:          files resolve dns
```

Now:

```
>ping jira.mycompany.local
PING jira.mycompany.local (192.168.100.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=7.04 ms
```

Works, but:

```
>ping jira
ping: jira: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

How can I debug this issue / or fix it?

Comment: When you use dig to diagnose DNS problems, always explicitely specify the nameserver you query with the `@` option. You have 3 nameservers, test each of them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using only on `search` line in you `resolv.conf`

```
search mycompany.local devnet.mycompany.nl
```

Secondly, your test with `dig` using only `jira` fails and that is a normal behavior! `dig` won't auto-complete your hostname with the domains specified in `resolv.conf`.

Comment: What is a valid way to verify if the search list works in that case? How can I just type in `jira` and check by attaching which domain out of my search list resolved?